# Node.JS - Output content from multiple JSON files into console

Tags: json, node.js, console

I am very new to Node.js and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around outputting the contents of multiple JSON files.

Inside my project folder, I have a script.js file as well as a folder with multiple JSON files (one.json, two.json, three.json, four.json).

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to display the contents of each JSON file in my console.

Answer (score 1):

```
// fs and path, core modules
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

// Get directory content
fs.readdir("./", (err, fileNames) => {
    // Loop fileNames array
    fileNames.forEach(filename => {
        // Get only .json files
        if (path.extname(filename) == ".json"){
            // Read file content
            fs.readFile("./"+filename, "utf-8", (err, content) => {
                // Log file content
                console.log(content);
            });
        }
    });
});
```